# Order of Cyclic Group Generated by $1 + i$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to find the order of the cyclic subgroup of the group $\mathbb{C}^\times$  (non zero complex numbers) generated by $(1+i)$.  Well, I know that in polar form, the angle of $1 + i$ is $\pi/4$.  So angle of $(1+i)^2$ is $\pi/2$, etc.  So this makes me think this cyclic subgroup has order 8.

My book says something along the lines of:

"$\lvert 1+i\rvert$ is $\sqrt2$, so the order of this cyclic subgroup is infinite."

Totally confused on this explanation...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: But the distance from the origin is $\sqrt2$, and this multiplies, so as you take higher powers, the distance goes to infinity too.

Comment: HINT: $(1+i)^4=(1-1+2i)^2=-4$ and so $-4\in\langle i+1\rangle$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that when you take higher powers of $1+i$ then the argument just keeps cycling through $\pi / 4, \pi / 2 , 3\pi/4, \dots$. But the modulus of the higher powers will grow without bound. So you can't find an $n>1$ such that $(1+i)^n = 1$. (Remember that in a finite cyclic group for each element $x$ you can find an $n$ such that $x^n = 1$.)

Answer (score 7):

Recall that $|z^n| = |z|^n$. We have $|1+\mathrm{i}|=\sqrt{2}$ and so $|(1+\mathrm{i})^n|=|1+\mathrm{i}|^n = (\sqrt{2})^n$.

If $g_n = (1+\mathrm{i})^n$ then $g_i \neq g_j$ for $i \neq j$ because $|g_i| \neq |g_j|$.

In words: each power will give a different complex number, because they will have different moduli.